# How to obtain missing Observable information following a timeout

Tags: rx-groovy

If I have an Observable created with ten items where three of them exceed a timeout threshold then how can I produce a final result that has all of the completed items and the items that did not complete partitioned for a complete report.

The following Groovy code works by applying a timeout of 15 seconds of inactivity but only contains data for the completed work leaving the user without any information about the status of the missing items.

```
getListOfReports ()
.flatMap { report -> getReport_Async (report) }
.timeout (15, SECONDS)
.onErrorResumeNext (Observable.empty ())
```

function getListOfReports returns an Observable (synchronous - from a database).  Function getReport_Async returns an Observable (asynchronous sql from multiple databases).

I suspect that a Subject will be involved which will hold a second subscription and will somehow produce a difference operation following the timeout event.  I am struggling to work this out without going to extreme measures involving side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I broke the problem down and mocked up an example.  By splitting the overall process into small pieces, I put some of the pieces together to form a solution.  This is likely not the best solution but until a better one is posted, the following Groovy code works.

```
// utility function to print values emitted by observable, exception notification, and observable completion
def oPrint (String name, Observable observable) {
  observable
  .subscribe (
    { value -> println "$name: $value" }
  , { exception -> println "Exception ($name): ${exception.message}" }
  , { -> println "$name: ended" }
  )
}

// obtain list of reports to generate
def reports = Observable.range (1, 10)
.publish ()

// produce reports (some will take awhile)
def work = reports
.flatMap (
  { report -> 
    Observable.create { subscriber ->
      if (report in [5, 6]) Thread.sleep 5_000L
      subscriber.onNext report
      subscriber.onCompleted ()
    }
    .subscribeOn (Schedulers.io ())
  }
, { original, derived -> [value: original, status: 'success', result: derived] }
)
.publish ()

// all reports will be persisted for later viewing without redoing the work 
def persist = work
.publish ()

// reports completed before a timeout will be passed through
def timed = work
.timeout (3, SECONDS)
.onErrorResumeNext (Observable.empty ())
.publish ()

// determine which reports did not complete prior to timeout
def delta = Observable.combineLatest (
  reports.toList ()
, timed.map { result -> result.value }.toList ()
) { full, partial ->
  Observable.from (full - partial)
}
.flatMap { observable -> observable }
.map { report -> [value: report, status: 'timeout'] }
.publish ()

// combine partially completed list with delta list with timeout status 
def online = Observable.concat (
  timed
, delta
)
.publish ()

// output final contents 
oPrint "persist", persist
oPrint "online", online

// start all of the connectable observables 
online.connect ()
delta.connect ()
timed.connect ()
persist.connect ()
work.connect ()
reports.connect ()

// wait until all observables have completed 
Thread.sleep 10_000L

/*** start of output ***

online: [value:7, status:success, result:7]
persist: [value:7, status:success, result:7]
online: [value:1, status:success, result:1]
persist: [value:1, status:success, result:1]
online: [value:2, status:success, result:2]
persist: [value:2, status:success, result:2]
online: [value:3, status:success, result:3]
persist: [value:3, status:success, result:3]
online: [value:4, status:success, result:4]
persist: [value:4, status:success, result:4]
online: [value:8, status:success, result:8]
persist: [value:8, status:success, result:8]
online: [value:9, status:success, result:9]
persist: [value:9, status:success, result:9]
online: [value:10, status:success, result:10]
persist: [value:10, status:success, result:10]
online: [value:5, status:timeout]
online: [value:6, status:timeout]
online: ended
persist: [value:5, status:success, result:5]
persist: [value:6, status:success, result:6]
persist: ended

*** end of output ***/
```